# Why does Eclipse 'filter results from view' when searching?

Tags: eclipse

Often when I'm searching for referenced types, Eclipse search will return no actual results but provide the message `(3 matches filtered from view)` .. for example.

Why is it filtering results and how do I disable this?

thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you click the down arrow at the top right corner of the Search pane [image: Eclipse arrow for popup menus] then you will get a popup menu with *Filters...* second from the bottom. You will then see a dialog with *Select the matches to exclude from the search results:* Untick the options in the list as needed. I think the default is only to exclude search results in imports.

[image: Eclipse Search Filters]

Comment: Thanks, this problem has been bugging me. I had visited the Search Filters window, but assumed it was _include_, not _exclude_. Include would have been more intuitive.

Comment: they should really rename it to "filter OUT", filter usually means "filter IN", just read that non bold "exclude"...